# reached the maximum number of available Distribution certificates

Tags: ios, fastlane

I was trying to do `fastlane match development` and that blocked me with the following error message:

> Could not create another Distribution certificate, reached the maximum number of available Distribution certificates.

I have only one, so I'm not so sure what's going on here.

Comment: check in developper.apple.com in your account under certificate is should be more than one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resolution for me turned out to be that I did not have any Devices in the developer portal anymore.

(Apple walked me through resetting the list for some reason.)

Once I added my iPhone UDID I could do nuke and match development cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

login in https://developer.apple.com/ and remove one of your Distribution certificates

Answer (score 0):

Also worth noting that you get this error when you use the same name for the certificates. fastlane match was using certificate name of under "Team iOS", once I revoked this certificate from developer portal, I was able to run match again without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are able to create any certificates on Apple Developer account in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles. If not - follow instructions / perform actions there.

So one of the options is to remove development certificate and re-generate a new one.

[image: dev-certs]